# Is it possible to check that internet connection is tethered using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, tethering

I was wondering if it is possible to detect a tethered connection, say I am connected to my phone on my mac, and would like to check if mac is using a tethered connection.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? What if someone's using a fast mobile connection without data limits? What if they're using an old dial-up connection, slow as hell, and paid by minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using the help of an outside observer, and how in-depth you want the solution to be. For example, you could query an external server and ask which IP address they see you requesting from - using this information you could determine whether you're on your mobile ISP or your home ISP.

If you need this solution to apply to random users/visitors it is probably infeasible, and I don't think there is any other solution.

Comment: Nothing will be able to reveal the last few meters are actually a home WiFi, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak you're right, this will only work if you're tethered via your mobile data plan and not your home wifi.